# OSX Server Cannot Find itself

Tags: osx-server, profile-manager, netboot

Everything was working perfectly last week when I left it and no-one (accessible by only 4 people in our IT department) has touched it.

Okay, we use OS X server and Deploy Studio to manage our apple devices. Today, however, deploy Studio was not reachable. I could Netboot a Macbook to the Deploy Studio Assistant, but upon logging in the server and repository could not be reached.

Now I then went to check in settings and open the URL of the repository but, again, server cannot be found. I restarted the service and it would not finish config. Restarted and had the same issue (also said repository cannot be found).

Then I tested Profile Manager. I opened the link on the server itself and 'Safari Can't Find the Server'.

Does anyone know what might cause this? I did renew push certificates last week but everything was running smoothly and no other changes have been made.

Thank you!

Comment: This question's title almost sounded philosophical.

Comment: Dude :) Have done some more testing and it seems the server's name is not being resolved. So, I guess the server more doesn't know who it is anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Seems someone had been fiddling with the DNS server :) All good now!